# Problems trying to fetch Cloud Firestore data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Okay, i have this structure on my Cloud Firestore:

```
Collection question:
- userID
- text

and Collection user:
- name 
- key
```

I can easily retrieve the question data from the database and return it, but without the user data for now. Them i need do another search in database foreach comment returned previously. However I am having a lot of problems trying to do this.

First:

I do this for search the questions:

Component:

```
export class ListQuestionsComponent implements OnInit {
  tableData: Question[] = [];
  userData: User[] = [];

constructor(
      private questionService: QuestionService,
      private userService: UserService,
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadItens();
    this.getUsers();
  }

loadItens() {
    this.questionService.loadItems().subscribe(response => {
      this.tableData = [];
      for (const item of response) {
        this.tableData.push(item.payload.doc.data() as Question);
      }
}
```

Question Service:

```
loadItems() {
    const query = ref => ref
    .limit(10);

    return this.firestore.collection('perguntas', query).snapshotChanges();
}
```

This works and now I have the questions in my tableData. Now I need search the user for each of this questions.

I try do this in the same Component:

```
getUsers() {
 for(const item of this.tableData) {
   this.userService.getUserByKey(item.userID).subscribe(response => {
      this.userData = [];
      for (const user of response) {
        this.userData.push(user.payload.doc.data() as User);
      }
   });
 }
}
```

User Service

```
getUserByKey(key: string) {
    return this.firestore.collection('users', ref => ref
      .where('key', '==', key))
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

At end of all I have a tableData with 10 questions, and userData without nothing. I don't know what to do now. I only need the users who are referenced in the questions I sought.

Comment: Have you considered storing the required user data with the question? This would allow you to pull the questions and have all the data you need. To achieve this, on question submission you store the user's data, and if necessary you can use a cloud function to look for future user info changes (on change, update all questions where the user exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches, the methodology that I've adopted with Firestore is to store the data that I think I will need with the data I'm pulling.

So if I were to pull `questions` and I know I will need a `user`, their `username`, and their `profile picture`, then I will store a user field in each question document that has the user's ID, username, and profile picture.

Something like:

```
Questions:
---> Question
---> Date
---> User:
-------> ID
-------> Profile Picture
-------> Username
```

Update:

The thing that you will need to make a decision on is how much of the user's data can stay out-of-date and which bits of data need to remain updated. For anything that needs to remain update, like usernames that may affect routing, you can listen for changes to your core user collection:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      const newName = newValue.name;
      const oldName = previousValue.name;

      if (newName !== oldName){
          //update all questions where userId matches.
      }

      // perform other desired operations ...
    });
```

You can see this part of the documentation for more information on Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, but if you needed to change your username would you need to change each question?

Comment: Yup! I just updated the answer on the way I do that using Firebase Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, researching a little about asynchronous function has achieved some result. I changed some things in the code.

Variable user data become

**userData: any;**

Inside of the subscribe of my **loadItems()** i call **getUsers()**

and my **getUsers()**

```
getUsers() {    
  for (const item of this.tableData) {
    this.usuarioService.getUserByKey(item.userId).subscribe(response => {
      this.userData[item.userId] = response[0].payload.doc.data();
    });
  }
}
```