# How to perform nested queries in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to perform a database request containing an array of incidents, where every Incident has the id of the reporter. So before I return that array of Incidents, I need to map the corresponding user to the corresponding incident. The query should look something like this: 
1. query collection('/incidents)
2. return that incidents in the end, but before returning it
-> go through every entry in that array of incidents and query the appropriate reporter of that incident. Asign that reporter to that incident and after that return the whole array.

So the result I search for looks something like this: 
- incident in fire store has this properties:

```
Incident: {
 id: string;
 likes: number;
 reportedBy: string;
}
```

- incident I want to display:

```
Incident: {
 id: string;
 likes: number;
 reportedBy: User;
}
```

Does anyone has an answer for me? I'm searching for a solution since days...

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948591/problems-trying-to-fetch-cloud-firestore-data/57949620#57949620):

In my view there's very little reason to make the calls on the client's side. Firestore is extremely fast but might as well make fewer calls when possible. The technique I've adopted with Firestore is to store the data that I think I will need with the data I'm pulling.

So if I were to pull `incidents` and I know I will need a `user`, their `username`, and their `profile picture`, then I will store a user field in each question document that has the user's ID, username, and profile picture.

Something like:

```
Incidents:
---> Incident
---> Date
---> ReportedBy:
-------> ID
-------> Profile Picture
-------> Username
```

Update:

The thing that you will need to make a decision on is how much of the user's data can stay out-of-date and which bits of data need to remain updated. For anything that needs to remain updated, like usernames that may affect routing, you can listen for changes to your core user collection:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      const newName = newValue.name;
      const oldName = previousValue.name;

      if (newName !== oldName){
          //update all incidents where userId matches.
      }

      // perform other desired operations ...
    });
```

You can see this part of the documentation for more information on Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated

Answer (score 0):

Firestore now supports nested queries. What I understood is that you want to search into “Incidents” collection and then for each incident assign its reporter. According to this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) in the official documentation you can get all documents from a collection with [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get).

```
db.collection("incidents").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
// fetching reportedBy info using .get field.
    console.log(doc.get(“reportedBy”));
    });
});
```

Let me know if this is helpful.